# How to get "is_active_trail" in pgmpy working?

Tags: python

I'm unable to get the code on [this webpage](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781784394684/1/ch01lvl1sec14/bayesian-models) to run. I don't see the function "is_active_trail" in [pgmpy](https://pgmpy.org/). Has it been changed or removed? How best to get the code to work?

```
from pgmpy.models import BayesianModel
model = BayesianModel()
model.add_nodes_from(['rain', 'traffic_jam'])
model.add_edge('rain', 'traffic_jam')
model.add_edge('rain', 'traffic_jam')
model.add_edge('accident', 'traffic_jam')
model.nodes()
from pgmpy.factors.discrete import TabularCPD
cpd_rain = TabularCPD('rain', 2, [[0.4], [0.6]])
cpd_accident = TabularCPD('accident', 2, [[0.2], [0.8]])
cpd_traffic_jam = TabularCPD(
                                'traffic_jam', 2,
                                [[0.9, 0.6, 0.7, 0.1],
                                 [0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.9]],
                                evidence=['rain', 'accident'],
                                evidence_card=[2, 2])

model.add_cpds(cpd_rain, cpd_accident, cpd_traffic_jam)
model.get_cpds()

model.add_node('long_queues')
model.add_edge('traffic_jam', 'long_queues')
cpd_long_queues = TabularCPD('long_queues', 2,
                                      [[0.9, 0.2],
                                       [0.1, 0.8]],
                                      evidence=['traffic_jam'],
                                      evidence_card=[2])
model.add_cpds(cpd_long_queues)
model.add_nodes_from(['getting_up_late',  
                               'late_for_school'])
model.add_edges_from(
                   [('getting_up_late', 'late_for_school'),
                    ('traffic_jam', 'late_for_school')])
cpd_getting_up_late = TabularCPD('getting_up_late', 2,
                                          [[0.6], [0.4]])
cpd_late_for_school = TabularCPD(
                               'late_for_school', 2,
                               [[0.9, 0.45, 0.8, 0.1],
                                [0.1, 0.55, 0.2, 0.9]],
                               evidence=['getting_up_late',
                                         'traffic_jam'],
                               evidence_card=[2, 2])
model.add_cpds(cpd_getting_up_late, cpd_late_for_school)
model.get_cpds()

model.check_model()

model.is_active_trail('accident', 'rain')
```

error:

### /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pgmpy/models/BayesianModel.py:10: FutureWarning: BayesianModel has been renamed to BayesianNetwork. Please use BayesianNetwork class, BayesianModel will be removed in future.
FutureWarning,

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
46 model.check_model()
47
---> 48 model.is_active_trail('accident', 'rain')

AttributeError: 'BayesianModel' object has no attribute 'is_active_trail'

Comment: That book were published in 2015. Maybe trying on older version of pgmpy will work. Just a guest.